# React Native App login with office 365 using react-native-app-auth npm package

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, office365

I am trying to authenticate my ios and android app with microsoft office 365 using react-native-app-auth package and not sure why it is not returning the token.

Here is the config that I am using:

```
const config = {
   issuer:
     'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/v2.0',
      clientId: '{client-id}',
      redirectUrl: 'msauth.org.xxx.xxx://auth',              // I got this from Azure
      scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'offline_access'],
    };
```

I have also tried with the below config

```
 const config = {
      clientId: AuthConfig.appId,
      warmAndPrefetchChrome: true,
      redirectUrl: 'msauth.org.xxx.xxx://auth',
      scopes: AuthConfig.appScopes,
      additionalParameters: {prompt: 'select_account'},
      serviceConfiguration: {
        authorizationEndpoint:
          'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' +
          AuthConfig.tenantId +
          '/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
        tokenEndpoint:
          'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' +
          AuthConfig.tenantId +
          '/oauth2/v2.0/token',
      },
    };
```

Here is the code:

```
const loginWithOffice365 = async () => {
    try {
      let result = await authorize(config);
      console.log('result', result);   // This is not showing any result and not even printing any error
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
    }
  }
```

I have registered the app correctly in Azure and this is the redirect url screenshot

[image]

It goes to office 365 page and I can enter my credentials and it says are you ready to login and I click continue, once I do that, it goes back to the login page. I am not sure if my redirect URL is correct because I am trying to print the token that I should get back from Microsoft.

I am just trying to print the access token. Can you please help and tell me how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your redirect url should be msauth.org.xxx.xxx://auth/

You are just missing an extra '/'